# Como saber se a aplicação está sendo executada em ambiente de desenvolvimento ou de produção?

Tags: c#, .net

Preciso verificar se a aplicação está sendo executada no meu computador (Windows 10) ou no servidor (Windows server) para saber se obtenho as credenciais do usuário de forma específicas em cada plataforma.

Procurando na internet achei algumas opções utilizando `Environment.OSVersion`, porém não estou conseguindo diferenciar se o Windows é versão desktop (10, 11) ou server:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        
        Console.WriteLine("OS Version: " + os.Version.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("OS Platoform: " + os.Platform.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("OS SP: " + os.ServicePack.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("OS Version String: " + os.VersionString.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Get Version details
        Version ver = os.Version;
        Console.WriteLine("Major version: " + ver.Major);
        Console.WriteLine("Major Revision: " + ver.MajorRevision);
        Console.WriteLine("Minor version: " + ver.Minor);
        Console.WriteLine("Minor Revision: " + ver.MinorRevision);
        Console.WriteLine("Build: " + ver.Build);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
        
        
    }
}
```

O resultado tem sido só "Windows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível, até porque precisaria definir o que é ambiente de desenvolvimento e o que é produção. O que é para você pode não ser para outra pessoa.

Inclusive o sistema operacional não determina se o ambiente é de produção ou não, só você sabe disso, talvez. E se mudar o local onde é a tal da produção?

Você pode verificar se é um Windows Server, mas aí não estaria determinando se é produção ou não, a não ser por uma convenção sua hoje, não de outras pessoas ou sua em outra momento ou situação, é um conceito errado. E se for rodar no Linux? tentar verificar qual é o sistema operacional é um critério, mas ficaria algo assim:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Se você definir que o ambiente de desenvolvimento é quando está rodando em modo *debug*, aí já tem uma solução, mas é a deteção deste modo apenas. Se não puder fazer assim não tem jeito.

Para facilitar pode criar uma função que retorne isto:

```
public static bool IsDebug() {
    #if DEBUG
        return true;
    #else
        return false;
    #endif
}
```

A forma de compilação determinará o que retornar. Será inclusive bem eficiente, ainda que isso não seja relevante para o caso.

Se na verdade quiser executar algo apenas se for um modo *debug* aí pode usar o atributo [`Conditional("DEBUG")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) em algum método restrito. Exemplo:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Foo() {}
```

Ainda pode verificar com o método [`Debugger.IsAttached()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=net-7.0).

Existem algumas outras técnicas mais sofisticadas dependendo do tipo de aplicação ([exemplo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) ou se você quiser fazer um arquivo de configuração que tenha essa informação, e aí você mantém arquivos diferentes em locais diferentes, mas essencialmente é problema da sua aplicação cuidar disto e o critério é seu do que é produção e o que é desenvolvimento, passaria não ser de como resolver como o que a linguagem e a BCL do .NET entrega para você. Essa solução é muito mais adequada que tentar verificar em qual sistema operacional está rodando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Debug.cs).

Comment: Debugger.IsAttached foi o suficiente para resolver o problema, obrigado Maniero!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode determinar se está em um Windows Server pela função [`IsOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-isos?redirectedfrom=MSDN) do *shlwapi.h*:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class OS
{
    public static bool IsWindowsServer()
    {
        return OS.IsOS(OS.OS_ANYSERVER);
    }

    const int OS_ANYSERVER = 0x1D;

    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="#437")]
    private static extern bool IsOS(int os);
}
```

E para chamar:

```
if(OS.IsWindowsServer()) {
    ///
}
```